# Active menu tab

Tags: javascript

Is there an error with this code that I'm missing? This should work, but it doesn't. I've tried all different versions of this with JavaScript and jQuery, it seems like it doesn't targeting the list element.

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll("#ul");
  for (var i = 0; length = a.length; i++) {
    a[i].onclick = function() {
      var b = document.querySelector("li.active");
      if (b) {
        b.classList.remove("active");
      }
      a[i].classList.add("active");
    };
  }
```

```css
               ul {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: row;
                    list-style: none;
                    align-items: center;
    
                    li {
                        margin-right: 1.875rem;
                        padding: 0 1rem;
                        font-size: 0.875rem;
                        text-align: center;
                        cursor: pointer;
                        
                        a {
                            text-decoration: none;
                            color: black;
                            font-weight: bold;
                        }
                        &:hover {
                            border-bottom: 3px solid $orange;
                        }
                    }
                }
                .active {
                    background-color: gray;
                    border-bottom: 3px solid $orange;
                }
```

````html
```<nav class="nav">
<ul id="#ul">
<li class="li active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="li" ><a href="#">Discover</a></li>
<li class="li"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
<li class="li"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
<li class="li" ><a href="#">Help</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
````

Comment: I guess it is because you grab ul in wrong way, should be 
```var a = document.getElementById("#ul");```
or
```var a = document.querySelectorAll("##ul");```

Answer (score 1):

As @mathk says, in your html body, change  `<ul id="#ul">` to `<ul id="ul">`

Now realize, since this is an id, which is unique, you can actually simplify your code to use `document.getElementById` instead of `document.querySelectorAll()` and having to iterate through an array of 1:

```
var a = document.getElementById("ul"); //instead of a = document.querySelectorAll("#ul")
```

Then you just do whatever to `a` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the `#` in the html id attribute. This `#` is for css only to distinguish which attribute is targeted.

Also be aware that you are not capturing the correct index in your handler. You should use `this` at some point.

Comment: `#` is a *valid* character to have in an ID. However, it does lead to confusion. So it's more of a practical constraint than a technological one.

Comment: Right, I missed the id typo, thanks, that was it. But the code wasn't working properly, I've changed it to this one: var li = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  li[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
  this.className += " active";
  });
}

Answer (score 0):

I tried to copy and modify you code and here are your mistakes;

1. **html selector** :
   you need to remove the `#` from `<ul id="#ul">`.
2. **get children from ul**
   to get the array of children from ul html component you need to specify `a[0].children` 
   a simple `console.log(a[0].children)` would show you the result.
3. **event lister**
   I suggest you to work with `addEventListener` in simple javascript, like this `a[i].addEventListener("click", function() {`
4. **change "active" child**
   when you work with `addEventListener` you can target the object that call the `onClick` event by `this.classList` like the code below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        list-style: none;
        align-items: center;

        li {
            margin-right: 1.875rem;
            padding: 0 1rem;
            font-size: 0.875rem;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;

            a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: black;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            &:hover {
                border-bottom: 3px solid $orange;
            }
        }
    }
    .active {
        background-color: gray;
        border-bottom: 3px solid $orange;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <ul id="ul">
  <li class="li active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="li" ><a href="#">Discover</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="li" ><a href="#">Help</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
var a = document.querySelectorAll("#ul");
console.log(a[0].children)
console.log(a[0].children.length)
a = a[0].children
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var b = document.querySelector("li.active");
    if (b) {
      b.classList.remove("active");
    }
    this.classList.add("active");
  })
}
</script>


               
</body>
</html>
```